# EJB 3.0 - Context.Lookup Failed loading apropriate EJB Beans

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic, jndi, web.xml

I'm working on EJB application, and i'm trying to use **lookup** approach but it fails at Runtime moment,

Here my code and configuration :

**weblogic.xml**

```
                    <ejb-reference-description>
                            <ejb-ref-name>
                                 RechercheClientSMBean
                            </ejb-ref-name>
                            <jndi-name>
                                *****-ejb/RechercheClientSMBean/local
                            </jndi-name>
                    </ejb-reference-description>
```

**Local Interface**

```
        @Local
        public interface IRechercheClientFacade extends Facade {}
```

**Bean Implementation**

```
                    @Stateless(name="RechercheClientSMBean", mappedName="RechercheClientSMBean")
                    public class RechercheClientSMBean extends AbstractBean implements IRechercheClientFacade { }
```

**web.xml**

```
                    <ejb-ref>
                        <ejb-ref-name>RechercheClientSMBean</ejb-ref-name>  
                        <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>  
                        <home>com.*****.***.app.service.common.client.RechercheClientSMBean</home>  
                    </ejb-ref>
```

**Bean Lookup Code**

```
                        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
                    iRechercheClientFacade= (IRechercheClientFacade)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/RechercheClientSMBean");
```

It results into the following Exception :

> weblogic.deployment.EnvironmentException:
>   The ejb-link 'RechercheClientSMBean' declared in the ejb-ref or ejb-local-ref 'RechercheClientSMBean' in the application module 'pfi.war' could not be resolved. The target EJB for the ejb-ref could not be found. Please ensure the link is correct.

I checked every possible configuration, every naming possibility but i keep getting this same problem.

**PS**: the project is divided into multiple modules, the lookup method is made from web container.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you cannot use `@Inject` or `@EJB` in the class where you do the lookup, right?

Comment: As i said i tried all of them but nothing did work quiet expected, @EJB if the web container and ejb container were synced together but they’re not

Comment: I was not exactly sure what your PS part really meant, so thanks for clarifying this. To bad I have no idea how I can help on this.

Comment: What versions of weblogic and javaee are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:
ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/RechercheClientSMBean");